# Adding Two Classes to ArrayList<Class> fills the arraylist with two duplicates

Tags: java, class, arraylist, bukkit, generic-list

I made an ArrayList called `ArrayList<Arena>` as I am making a Spigot plugin.

```
public static ArrayList<Arena> all = new ArrayList<Arena>();
```

now I have my class and this is the instanciation step:

```
public Arena(String name, int min, int max) {
    Arena.name = name;
    Arena.layout = "default";
    Arena.customName = CManager.getPlugin().getArenaConfig().getString("arenas." + name + ".custom-name");

    ArenaManager.addToArenaList(this);
    ArenaManager.arenaNames.add(Arena.name);
    Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "[" + plugin.getPdfFile().getName()
            + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " [#] (Instanciated arena " + Arena.name + ")");

    Arena.min = min;
    Arena.max = max;
    Arena.world = Bukkit.getWorld(Arena.name);

    waiting = true;
    starting = false;
    game = false;
    finished = false;
}
```

I have an issue with this seemingly simple piece of code.

```
public static void addToArenaList(Arena a) {
    all.add(a);
    checkArena(a);
}

public static void checkArena(final Arena a) {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!(all.contains(a))) {
                Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(
                        ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "[" + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.RED
                                + " [E] (Error while adding arena " + a.getArenaName() + "to list)");
            } else {
                Boolean found = false;
                for (Arena f : all) {
                    if (f.getArenaName().equals(a.getArenaName())) {
                        if (found == true) {
                            Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender()
                                    .sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "[" + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]"
                                            + ChatColor.RED + " [E] (Duplicate found with arena "
                                            + a.getArenaName());
                            continue;
                        }
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (found == false) {
                    Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender()
                            .sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "[" + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]"
                                    + ChatColor.RED + " [E] (Error while adding arena " + a.getArenaName()
                                    + "to list)");
                }
            }
        }
    }, 10L);
}
```

But for some reason I get duplicates of the last Arena, also here is the first stage of the process

```
public void onEnable() {
    Methods.sendColoredMessage(this, ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE, ("Registering Commands...."), ChatColor.YELLOW);
    registerCommands();
    Methods.sendColoredMessage(this, ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE, ("Registering Events...."), ChatColor.YELLOW);
    registerEvents();
    Methods.sendColoredMessage(this, ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE, ("Registering Config...."), ChatColor.YELLOW);
    createFiles();
    Methods.sendColoredMessage(this, ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE, ("Attempting to load arenas...."), ChatColor.GOLD);
    ArenaManager.all.clear();
    ArenaManager.arenaNames.clear();
    ArenaManager.createArenas();
    Methods.sendColoredMessage(this, ChatColor.AQUA,
            (pdfFile.getName() + " has been enabled! (V." + pdfFile.getVersion() + ")"), ChatColor.GREEN);
}
public static void createArenas() {
    if (plugin.getArenaConfig().getConfigurationSection("arenas") != null) {
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<String> listed = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String arena : plugin.getArenaConfig().getStringList("enabled")) {
            count++;
            Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender()
                    .sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "[" + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]"
                            + ChatColor.GREEN + " [" + count + "] (Loading arena " + arena + ")");
            int min = plugin.getArenaConfig().getInt("arenas." + arena + ".min");
            int max = plugin.getArenaConfig().getInt("arenas." + arena + ".max");

            new Arena(arena, min, max);
        }
        Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "["
                + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " [A] Loaded arenas are listed below:");
        for (Arena a : all) {
            if (listed.contains(a.getArenaName())) {
                continue;
            }
            Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "["
                    + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " [A] - " + a.getArenaName());
            listed.add(a.getArenaName());
        }
    } else {
        Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "["
                + plugin.getPdfFile().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.RED + " [E] No arenas have been found!");
    }
}
```

So if I had 4 arenas and the last one was called EndArena, in my array, I will end up with 4 elements all with the same Arena class EndArena. I have tried everything, and I don't usually like asking for help (i prefer learning things myself) but this has annoyed me for so long that I have to submit it.

Also here is my arena **YAML** file

[YAML Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ZL7.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you don't use objects correctly.

As far as I understood your code you want to create some kind of Arena, assigning some values to that Arena and then add it to some ArenaManager. This is fine. In order to do that you need to use instance variables, so every created Arena would have its own name. Unique to that particular instance.

You are using static fields here - the static is the same across all objects in the program, which is not what you need here (it would be beneficial if you need something like Arena counter).

Please see some example:

Imagine there is really simple and naive Person class (following your approach).

```
public class Person {
    private static String name;
    public Person(String name) {
         Person.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you would do something like:
    new Person("Adam");
    new Person("Viktor");

You would end with 2 person instances having (pointing) to one static variable which in the end would have value Victor. Which surely is not something we need here. In order to have this working properly you need to use instance variables:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now after our sample code you would have 2 persons, every with different name. It doesn't really matter how you accessing them, what really matters here is they should be instance fields - meaning every instance has separate block in memory to hold this value. If the field is static it simply means there is one possible variable value for all different object - everytime you change it will be changed for all other objects.

So to sum this up:

You should use instance fields and not static fields.

In your constructor you have:
    Arena.name = name;
    Arena.layout = "default";

Those two lines of code always overwrite static field in your Arena class.

In your Arena class you have something like (note static keyword):

```
private static String name;
```

You need to have:

```
private String name;
```

so every instance has got its own name. Please read about instances and static fields this will make it much easier to understand! Here is the sample document from the Java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html
The tutorial will cover this all really nicely!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean here. Are you saying that I shouldn't use any static fields in my class, instead use methods to access them?

Comment: I can elaborate a bit on my answer.
Generally static field is the same across all instances of the object. What you need here is instance field - after all you are assigning values in constructor which would hint you need them to have  different. 
What you are doing here is giving the same name across all Arena instances, which is clearly not you want. Let me add some examples in my answer :)

Comment: Modified answer with some additional explanation and text. Let me know if this is a bit more clearer now! I would suggest going through Java tutorial it is really good explaining that kind of stuff.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I figured it out now. Your comment really helped. Saved me a lot of stress!

Comment: Please accept my answer then will get some reputation! You are welcome! ;)